# Add 2 local string[] into a single array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, var

we are receiving two strings from 2 client computers to our 3rd server computer. The array are currently 1 dimensional. We need to sum each member of the `result` and `answer` arrays to one another and output a third array. However we are using them as local variables`string[]`.

How can we add the values of `answer` and `result` into a single array.
For example:

```
answer[0]+result[0]= final[0]

..........

answer[76]+result[76]=final[76]
```

**Updated The Code**

```
    namespace ExampleLib.Server
{

    public class Server
    {
        string[] answer = new string[77];
        string[] result = new string[77];


    private void ClientReceiveData(object sender, ConnectedClient.NetDataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message) == false)
        {
        if (e.ID == 0)
                {
                    answer = e.Message.Split(',');
                }

                if (e.ID==1)
                {
                    result = e.Message.Split(',');                    
                }
                var final = answer.Zip(result, (x, y) => x + y).ToArray();

                Trace.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, final));

            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 1 (using Zip method):**
[image]

Comment: Do you mean length of the array or length of the value of it's members ?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. You can do it in a one-liner with LINQ, but if you're new to C# that may not help you learn as much. The "old-fashioned" way would be to create a new array of the right size, then use a `for` loop to populate it based on the existing arrays. However, there's another design issue at the moment: you'll need to save the arrays you receive as you receive them, as otherwise you'll only ever have one piece of data at a time.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Just to clarify, the strings we are receiving are coming from a TCP/IP stream from client computers, would a for loop still work ?

Comment: By the time you've got string arrays with the intended data in, how you got them is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... You have the same thing running for e.ID == 0 and e.ID == 1... Why not just combine the two conditions into one? The output would just be each string repeated by itself. Is that the intention?

Comment: the e.ID represents which client computer the data is coming from so ID =0 is from Client 1 and ID 1 is from Client 2. Without the if loop it will just print one string but we want to add the 2 client strings.

Comment: Right, but it doesn't matter which id it is, you're doing the same work on both. Are answer and result supposed to be local variables?

Comment: I updated the code and the my result on top

Comment: Makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use `Zip` method, like this:

```
var final = answer.Zip(result, (x, y) => x + y).ToArray();
```

Comment: If you're using `Zip`, why bother selecting each part separately? You can do whatever you want in that lambda expression, so you can make this one statement really easily: `var final = answer.Zip(result, (x, y) => x + y).ToArray();`

Comment: Where would I put the Zip method since both `answer` and `result` are declared in two different if loops?

Comment: If they are declared in different loops you just have to declare them outside of the loop and fill them in it.

Comment: we deeclared the varibles out the if loops like `string[] answer = new string[77];`
       `string[] result = new string[77];` however when we print the final string like ` Trace.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, final));` like so we see the results appear side by side and the arrays are not being added I will add a picture of the result I see on my question.

Comment: I think the problem here is not related to combining strings, but to the fact you only ever have either `answer` or `result` according to your code. There is no loop here, and you can't get both, because `e.ID` can't be both 0 and 1.

You need to first get data from both clients, pass it to other method, and only then combine it.

Comment: I see, okay we will modify the code so we can combine the string.